# vertical centering a form in a div

Tags: html, css, forms

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left-child">
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="right-child">
        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" value="search">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to vertical center `right-child` form when `left-child` logo height increases.

Can someone help me?

PS: Logo will be uploaded by user. So I have no idea about the logo height.

Comment: You'll have to use JavaScript to calculate the height of each div, then determine the top margin as (DIV_left - DIV_right)/2 and apply the margin to the form

Comment: What CSS do you have already?

Comment: @j08691 my form has this css code `form {
margin: 0 0 20px;
}` .

Comment: You WILL have an idea about the image height - You can get that when the user uploads it... i.e. in the server side code

Comment: @PaulSullivan Ahh. Got it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a new div to fit your form in a vertical way. I hope it works. I fixed the image width, but, you can delete this. http://jsfiddle.net/BfZFJ/

Your CSS:

```
.parent {
    border: 1px dashed red;
    display: table;        
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .left-child img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .left-child {
    border: 1px dashed blue;        
  }

  .right-child {
    border: 1px dashed green;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;                        
  }

  #your_form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
  }
```

your html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left-child">
        <img src="icons.jpg" alt="logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="right-child">
        <div id="your_form">
          <form action="#">
              <input type="text" value="search" />
          </form>            
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Hugs,
Vin.

Comment: Table layout (through CSS, not non-semantic) for the win... This will do until flexible boxes are supported in more browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-align: middle` if your divs are `display: inline-block`, but not if you're using floats:

```
.left-child,
.right-child {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mugGY/

However, be aware that `inline-block` is [not supported in older browsers like IE7](http://caniuse.com/inline-block)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left-child">
        <div><img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-child">
        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" value="search1" /><br/>
            <input type="text" value="search2" /><br/>
            <input type="text" value="search3" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.left-child {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
}
.left-child div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.right-child {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}

.right-child form {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Credits](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ft69z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The better answer in the future will be using the flex box model

- http://flexiejs.com/playground/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes
- http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Here's the CSS to support what you need http://jsfiddle.net/BfZFJ/1/

```
.parent {
    /* Use flex box layout to layout its children */
    display: box;
    /* Vertically center its children */
    box-align: center;    
}    

.right-child {
    /* The child on the right will take up all the remaining horizontal space */
    box-flex: 1;
}

/* Don't have to do anything to left-child, it automatically takes up its natural size */
```

Note that in the real world (for now), you'll need to use the vendor prefixes:

- display: [-webkit-box, -moz-box]
- -webkit-box-flex, -moz-box-flex
- -webkit-box-align, -moz-box-align